Finding whether a mixed nash equilibrium exists in a 3 player game
In this game, there are three agents and two tasks. 
$c_i$ denotes the cost of agent $i$'s effort. (In this case $c_1 = 1, c_2 = 2, c_3 = 3$) 
$V_j$ denotes the reward for the tasks. (In this case $V_1 = 2, V_2 = 1$)
The effort that agent $i$ spends on task $j$ is $x_{ij}$, where $\sum_j x_{ij} = 1, \forall i$. 
$p_{ij} = \frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_k x_{kj}}$ denotes the probability that agent $i$ is awarded task $j$ 
Therefore the expected utility for an agent is: $E[u_{ij}] = p_{ij} V_{j} - c_i x_{ij}.$
How can I show if a mixed Nash equilibrium exists? If it does, can I calculate it manually or with code?
